# Failed to compile C code for including problem

Tags: c, ubuntu, makefile, include

I have a c code where i want to use an Hardware API ([RTL SDR](https://github.com/osmocom/rtl-sdr)) and this an example of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "/home/user/rtl-sdr/src/convenience/convenience.h"
#include "/home/user/rtl-sdr/include/rtl-sdr.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int dev_index = 0;
   dev_index = verbose_device_search("0");
   return 0;
}
```

and this is the makefile that i used :

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -O0 -c -Wall
LDFLAGS= 

SOURCES=$ fm_rx.c
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)

EXECUTABLE=fm_rx

all: $(TASKMAP) $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@ -lm

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -lm -o $@

clean: 
    rm -fr $(OBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLE)
```

whenever i compile i get this kind of errors:

```
make all 
gcc -O0 -c -Wall fm_rx.c -lm -o fm_rx.o
In file included from fm_rx.c:6:0:
/home/user/rtl-sdr/src/convenience/convenience.h:55:18: error: unknown type name ‘rtlsdr_dev_t’; did you mean ‘__dev_t’?
 int nearest_gain(rtlsdr_dev_t *dev, int target_gain);
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
                  __dev_t
/home/user/rtl-sdr/src/convenience/convenience.h:65:27: error: unknown type name ‘rtlsdr_dev_t’; did you mean ‘__dev_t’?
 int verbose_set_frequency(rtlsdr_dev_t *dev, uint32_t frequency);
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
                           __dev_t
/home/user/rtl-sdr/src/convenience/convenience.h:75:29: error: unknown type name ‘rtlsdr_dev_t’; did you mean ‘__dev_t’?
 int verbose_set_sample_rate(rtlsdr_dev_t *dev, uint32_t samp_rate);
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
                             __dev_t
/home/user/rtl-sdr/src/convenience/convenience.h:85:29: error: unknown type name ‘rtlsdr_dev_t’; did you mean ‘__dev_t’?
 int verbose_direct_sampling(rtlsdr_dev_t *dev, int on);
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
                             __dev_t
Makefile:16: recipe for target 'fm_rx.o' failed
/home/user/rtl-sdr/src/convenience/convenience.h:94:27: error: unknown type name ‘rtlsdr_dev_t’; did you mean ‘__dev_t’?
 int verbose_offset_tuning(rtlsdr_dev_t *dev);
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
                           __dev_t
.
.
.
fm_rx.c: In function ‘main’:
fm_rx.c:12:8: warning: variable ‘dev_index’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    int dev_index = 0;
        ^~~~~~~~~
make: *** [fm_rx.o] Error 1
```

## edit

this is the directory structure
anouar@anouar-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y510P:~/rtl-sdr$ tree -d

```
.
├── build
│   ├── CMakeFiles
│   │   ├── 3.10.2
│   │   │   └── CompilerIdC
│   │   │       └── tmp
│   │   ├── CMakeTmp
│   │   └── uninstall.dir
│   ├── include
│   │   └── CMakeFiles
│   └── src
│       └── CMakeFiles
│           ├── convenience_static.dir
│           │   └── convenience
│           ├── rtl_adsb.dir
│           ├── rtl_eeprom.dir
│           ├── rtl_fm.dir
│           ├── rtl_power.dir
│           ├── rtl_sdr.dir
│           ├── rtlsdr_shared.dir
│           ├── rtlsdr_static.dir
│           ├── rtl_tcp.dir
│           └── rtl_test.dir
├── cmake
│   └── Modules
├── contrib
├── debian
│   └── source
├── include
├── m4
└── src
    ├── convenience
    └── getopt
```

I know the path of the include files and librtlsdr.a file but i don't know how to include them ... Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Look at the -I and -L flags of GCC
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.0/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options

Comment: tried that but it does not work

Comment: Do you have more headers under "/home/user/rtl-sdr/"? Probably one more header needs to be included first.

Comment: i will show you the tree of directories under rtl-sdr there is a whole directory for it

Comment: A directory tree does not show any header files. You might want to grep for a header file defining `rtlsdr_dev_t` and include that header.

Comment: Does `/home/user/rtl-sdr/src/convenience/convenience.h` try to include `rtl-sdr.h` with a wrong path? Maybe you could include rtl-sdr.h first?

Answer (score 0):

Putting absolute paths for including files in your code is not goog idea. I recommend you to leave only the include file names or the last part of the path in your code:

```
...
#include <string.h>
#include "convenience/convenience.h"
#include "rtl-sdr.h"
...
```

To help the compiler find those files you should use the -I flag. For example for the previous file you could use this CFLAGS in your Makefile:

```
CFLAGS= -O0 -c -Wall -I/home/user/rtl-sdr/src -I/home/user/rtl-sdr/include
```

This way you make your code non dependent of the paths of your libraries. Once that you do this, you will have to find in which include is declared the missing type. You can do this:

```
grep -r rtlsdr_dev_t /home/user/rtl-sdr
```

The exit will show where is that type used and, if any, where it is declared.

Once that you find the file where it is declared add the corresponding include to your code and, if needed, the corresponding path with -I to the CFLAGS in your Makefile.

EDIT:

The exact problem that you are seeing is caused because convenience.h is using the type rtlsdr_dev_t before it is defined in rtl-sdr.h. Put the rtl-sdr.h include before the convenience.h.

Comment: the same problem .... the `rtlsdr_dev_t` is in `/home/user/rtl-sdr/include/rtl-sdr.h`and defined as following `typedef struct rtlsdr_dev rtlsdr_dev_t`